# Using jq to slice up a very large JSON file based on a particular associative key

Tags: jq

Suppose I have a very large JSON file containing an array with millions of entries that have these keys (and many others)

```json
 {
        "name": "assets/fUCcxWczWT0",
        "displayName": "The House",
        "authorName": "John Smith",
        "resources": {"house" : "address","car":"bla"},
 }
```

How do I use `jq` to slice away (remove) what came before a particular name key? For example, everything before the element identified uniquely by `"name": "assets/fUCcxWczWT0"`.

The above is a simplified representative element from the file. Here is an actual element in the top-level array:

```json
{
  "name": "assets/4vds6twPsb7",
  "displayName": "pim",
  "authorName": "Erwin Braak",
  "createTime": "2017-12-06T11:52:40.557236Z",
  "updateTime": "2020-10-07T09:49:08.752848Z",
  "formats": [
    {
      "root": {
        "relativePath": "Pim.gltf",
        "url": "https://poly.googleapis.com/downloads/fp/1602064148752848/4vds6twPsb7/c8Ksvo0_VjG/Pim.gltf",
        "contentType": "model/gltf+json"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "relativePath": "Pim.bin",
          "url": "https://poly.googleapis.com/downloads/fp/1602064148752848/4vds6twPsb7/c8Ksvo0_VjG/Pim.bin",
          "contentType": "application/octet-stream"
        },
        {
          "relativePath": "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/pom/pimSurface_Color.png",
          "url": "https://poly.googleapis.com/downloads/fp/1602064148752848/4vds6twPsb7/c8Ksvo0_VjG/C:/Users/PC/Desktop/pom/pimSurface_Color.png",
          "contentType": "image/png"
        }
      ],
      "formatComplexity": {
        "triangleCount": "586149"
      },
      "formatType": "GLTF2"
    },
    {
      "root": {
        "relativePath": "Pim.obj",
        "url": "https://poly.googleapis.com/downloads/fp/1602064148752848/4vds6twPsb7/5QVGpvfauVK/Pim.obj",
        "contentType": "text/plain"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "relativePath": "Pim.mtl",
          "url": "https://poly.googleapis.com/downloads/fp/1602064148752848/4vds6twPsb7/5QVGpvfauVK/Pim.mtl",
          "contentType": "text/plain"
        },
        {
          "relativePath": "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/pom/pimSurface_Color.png",
          "url": "https://poly.googleapis.com/downloads/fp/1602064148752848/4vds6twPsb7/5QVGpvfauVK/C:/Users/PC/Desktop/pom/pimSurface_Color.png",
          "contentType": "image/png"
        }
      ],
      "formatComplexity": {
        "triangleCount": "586149"
      },
      "formatType": "OBJ"
    }
  ],
  "thumbnail": {
    "relativePath": "4vds6twPsb7.png",
    "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/C_il4QubLWYMAyrnGPMjXWx4E7MVYLZAoX_Hf-qr4WyHfebvf2y3lndh71A350g",
    "contentType": "image/png"
  },
  "license": "CREATIVE_COMMONS_BY",
  "visibility": "PUBLIC",
  "isCurated": true,
  "presentationParams": {
    "orientingRotation": {
      "w": 1
    },
    "colorSpace": "LINEAR",
    "backgroundColor": "#eeeeee"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your JSON objects flat? or do they have nested objects (the one you want to modify)

Comment: there are nested objects, but the name key is flat

Comment: What do you mean by "slice away what came before a particular name key"? Can you provide an example of a small json file with "simplified" elements (like in your first example), what you want to remove, and what your expected output it?

Comment: I mean all the elements before that element, defined by the "name"=key

Comment: Can you provide a **full example** of a small json file with "simplified" elements (like in your first example), what you want to remove, and what your **expected output** is? If you expect anyone to help you, we need some file we could use as input, and we need to know what the expected output is.

Comment: What is the importance of this json object being very large. Have you already run into performance or memory problems, are you looking for a low memory solution?

Comment: hey @kusalananda thanks for reviving this old question - i am glad that the bounty is attracting new expert blood answers below!

Answer (score 3):

On top of the file size problem, the main obstacle to an efficient solution here is that `jq` reasons in terms of *whole* objects, which means that arrays too are handled *either* as a whole *or* nothing.  Consequently we need to get rid of the main huge array containing the elements, in order to handle these latter as a stream of (much) smaller objects all along the way from the original input up to, and **including**, the final output.

In order to obtain this we do need some text manipulation, so as not to use `jq`'s array handling facilities even for the final output array.  I could think of a few variants, each having some (variable) degree of work to be done via text manipulation, but I'm going for the variant that limits such manipulation to the absolutely bare minimum of adding the syntax of an array structure for the final output only.

Such text manipulation is so minimal that we can use `jq`'s own text constructs for that purpose, which not only allows us to have a pure `jq`-only solution without resorting to additional tools, it also allows us to add the required bits of text while following the flow of the stream itself, thus without relying on expected indentation/newlines or any other formatting assumption, all to the benefit of a more robust way of "manually" building the final output array.  The cost for these advantages is a considerably uglier and less compact script than it could be if the text manipulation work were done through specialized tools such as `sed`.

A "one-liner" for the sample input might be like this:

```bash
jq -rn --stream --arg f name --arg q 'assets/fUCcxWczWT0' '"[", foreach fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs)) as $o ([null,null]; if .[1] or $o[$f]? == $q then [.[1], ","] else . end; .[0]//empty, if .[1] then $o else empty end), "]"'
```

The `jq` options used, the first three of which are necessary for correct results:

- `-r` for raw (i.e. not converted to JSON) output when arbitrary text is output
- `-n` for consuming input data through the `inputs` builtin *only*, or else the first whole object in input would be eaten up by `jq`'s regular looping
- `--stream` for using `jq`'s own Streaming mode of consuming input
- `--arg f name` the name of the field containing the value we look for
- `--arg q 'assets/fUCcxWczWT0'` the value we look for in the field of each object

Diving into the `jq` script alone, expanded and commented:

```jq
# Firstly, the initial bit of arbitrary text: the opening bracket for the final output,
# as required for a valid JSON array syntax

"[",

# Then a foreach statement, looping over the objects provided singularly, one by one,
# by the streamlined input
# NOTE 1: jq's streaming mode is used for this solution primarily so that we
#         can use `1 | truncate_stream()` here, which courteously (and natively)
#         strips the first (1 | ...) structure of the original input along the course of
#         the streamlined operation.
#         The first structure is obviously the main huge array containing the
#         objects, hence we receive these latter singularly in a truly streamlined
#         fashion, freed by the containment of the array
# NOTE 2: using `inputs | tostream` here in place of `--stream`, although functioning,
#         would not obtain the streaming goal, because it would first take the entire
#         input as a whole rather than streaming it from the start
    foreach fromstream( 1|truncate_stream(inputs) ) as $o (
        # the initial state of the loop: we use 2 values as a "shifting 2-value state-machine"
        # for the comma to be output (as text) along with all the elements except the
        # first. We use the second value as an overall state too
        [null, null];
        # here we look for the wanted value in the wanted field unless already found
        # previously according to the overall state, and we update the loop state "shifting"
        # the 2-state for the comma as soon as the wanted value is found
        if .[1] or $o[$f]? == $q then [.[1], ","] else . end;
        # here we print the comma text (if need be according to its 2-state)
        # as required for separating elements in a JSON array syntax, then we print
        # the object element itself if the overall state says so
        .[0]//empty, if .[1] then $o else empty end
    ),

# Lastly, the final bit of arbitrary text: the closing bracket for the output,
# as required for a valid JSON array syntax

"]"
```

A couple of final notes:

- obviously this approach assumes (and indeed takes advantage of the fact) that the original input is essentially flat and simple although huge: had it been a more complex overall structure, perhaps with cross-references between inner and outer values, the script would easily need to be likewise more complex and convoluted
- if we wanted to output the elements **up to** to the wanted one, instead of **starting from** the wanted one, the streaming logic could be a lot simpler, possibly with no need of a state at all, as in principle we could just `halt` the script on encountering the wanted object, thus also resulting a lot faster as a side effect (niceties of a fully streamed operation)

Answer (score 1):

A simplification of the problem, which can later be used to solve the original issue, is this: Without reading the whole document, how may one remove the first few elements of an array, such as

```json
[7,10,8,6,5,4,0,9,3,2,1]
```

... so that we get e.g.

```json
[4,0,9,3,2,1]
```

... where `4` was the input query to the solution?

Answer: Without caring whether we read the data into memory or not, we may solve this simpler problem by first "exploding" the input array into a set of individual digits and then finding the first of these that corresponds to our query. Once found, we put the found element and all subsequent digits into an array. We do this with two invocations of `jq` in a pipeline where the first `jq` will create a stream of digits, one per line:

```bash
$ jq '.[]' file | jq -c --argjson query 4 'select(. == $query) as $elem | [$elem, inputs]'
[4,0,9,3,2,1]
```

The issue is that the input and output data must be stored in memory; the input is parsed entirely by the first `jq` process, while the output is collected in memory by the second.

It would be neat if we could find a way to avoid storing the input data in memory. We may attempt to do that using the streaming feature of `jq`.  With `--stream`, the `jq` expression will receive a stream of arrays representing the current state of the input stream without having to parse the complete input (see ["Streaming"](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Streaming) section of the `jq` manual).

```bash
$ jq -c --stream --argjson query 4 'fromstream(select(.[1] == $query) as $elem | $elem, inputs | .[0][0] -= $elem[0][0])' file
[4,0,9,3,2,1]
```

The above `jq` command reads the stream representation of the array and finds the first element that corresponds to our query. It does this without storing the full input in memory.

The `.[1]` expression evaluates to the value of an array element, while `.[0][0]` corresponds to an element's index in the array (in general, the data in `.[0]` corresponds to the *path* of the value in the original non-streamed data set). For each element that we accept into the output, we must recalculate the element's index by offsetting it with the index of the found element. This avoids storing the *input* in memory, but we may still have to concede to storing the output in memory for conversion into non-streamed form.

Adapting the above command to something we can use with the original data is straightforward.  We must also test for the correct key in the object before comparing the key's value.  The element's key is stored in `.[0][1]`. **Note, however, that since we are receiving a *stream of incomplete objects*, finding the *complete* correct element based on the `name` key assumes that the `name` key is the *first* key in each element**. Were it the second or third key, we would have discarded the initial parts of that object.

```bash
$ cat file
[
   {
      "name": "assets/1",
      "authorName": "John Smith",
      "displayName": "The House",
      "resources": { "car": "bla", "house": "address" }
   },
   {
      "name": "assets/6",
      "authorName": "John Smith",
      "displayName": "The House",
      "resources": { "car": "bla", "house": "address" }
   },
   {
      "name": "assets/0",
      "authorName": "John Smith",
      "displayName": "The House",
      "resources": { "car": "bla", "house": "address" }
   },
   {
      "name": "assets/2",
      "authorName": "John Smith",
      "displayName": "The House",
      "resources": { "car": "bla", "house": "address" }
   }
]
```

The following removes all elements that precede the element with `assets/0` as its `name` value:

```bash
$ jq --stream --arg query 'assets/0' 'fromstream(select(.[0][1] == "name" and .[1] == $query) as $elem | $elem, inputs | .[0][0] -= $elem[0][0])' file
[
  {
    "name": "assets/0",
    "authorName": "John Smith",
    "displayName": "The House",
    "resources": {
      "car": "bla",
      "house": "address"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "assets/2",
    "authorName": "John Smith",
    "displayName": "The House",
    "resources": {
      "car": "bla",
      "house": "address"
    }
  }
]
```

To work around the limitation that the query key must be the first key in each object, we can do a 2-pass thing where we first determine the first index of our array element based on the `name` key, and then use that key to extract our data:

```bash
jq --stream --arg query 'assets/0' \
   'fromstream(select(.[0][1] == "name" and .[1] == $query) | [0,.[0][0]])' file |
   head -n 1 |
   jq --stream '.[1] as $index | fromstream(inputs | select(.[0][0] >= $index) | .[0][0] -= $index)' - file
```

The first `jq` in the above pipeline will output the indexes of all elements with a `name` field with the particular value we are looking for. The `head -n 1` picks the first of these indexes. The second `jq` reads the integer into the internal `$index` variable from standard input and then extracts any element from the input file (reading it for the second time) with an index equal to or greater than `$index`.

Comment: AFAICT you're still providing an array to `fromstream()`, though in its "streaming-encoded" form. Consequently it won't produce the output array until it has received the _whole_ input array albeit stripped of the unwanted elements. You can see it by providing the original array interactively one element per line: it won't output until you type the final closing bracket. Are you sure this doesn't store the output data in memory?

Comment: @LL3 Yes, We store the _output_ in memory. I made a note about this in my answer: "[...] but we may still have to concede to storing the output in memory for conversion into non-streamed form".  If you have a suggestion about how to get around this, I'd be interested in incorporating it. I believe storing only the output in memory is still better than storing both the input and output in memory, which the naive solution would do.

Comment: Ah, right, I had skipped that bit of the answer.  As for an alternative, I'd be interested myself.  The essential problem is that as soon as you want `jq` to output an array through its native means of array handling, it will invariably collect all the elements in memory before outputting them within the array. I'm afraid it's not possible to obtain a streaming-only solution without resorting to a little bit of arbitrary text, if not just to add the opening and closing brackets, plus a comma to separate each element, to build a valid array syntax